# Error whil passing date object as a part of Input Object to Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a result set being fetched from our Projects db. I am iterating over this resultset and putting it into an object array. 
There is only 1 column we are interested in, so we just assign it , while keeping everything else as null. Date objects are set to null inside the object array (I think this is the issue)

Then using ArrayDescriptor I am getting the oracle user-type of the input parameter of the Stored Proc

*ArrayDescriptor arraydesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("xyz.user_table_type", conn);*

This gets executed fine. 
However, I encounter an error on doing -

*ARRAY insertArray=new ARRAY(arraydesc,conn,object);*

Error i get is -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Non supported character set: oracle-character-set-178
    at oracle.gss.util.NLSError.throwSQLException(NLSError.java:46)
    at oracle.sql.CharacterSetUnknown.failCharsetUnknown(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:171)
    at oracle.sql.CharacterSetUnknown.convert(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:135)
    at oracle.sql.CHAR.<init>(CHAR.java:159)
    at oracle.sql.CHAR.<init>(CHAR.java:183)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCHAR.toDatum(OracleTypeCHAR.java:161)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toOracleArray(StructDescriptor.java:830)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toArray(StructDescriptor.java:1735)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.<init>(STRUCT.java:136)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.createObjSTRUCT(OracleTypeADT.java:2282)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatum(OracleTypeADT.java:247)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeADT.java:303)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeUPT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeUPT.java:117)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toOracleArray(ArrayDescriptor.java:1517)
    at oracle.sql.ARRAY.<init>(ARRAY.java:123)
    at RDT.RDTExtract.main(RDTExtract.java:114)
```

My db charset is AL32UTF8 and the stored proc db charset is WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: What Oracle-supplied JARs do you have on your classpath? And what versions of everything are you using - are you really connecting to an 11g database? I'm not sure what you mean about having two character sets - are you pulling data from an 11g database and then calling the procedure on a different (9i?) database?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the quick response. 

I have ojdbc14.jar and orai18n.jar in classpaths.
My project database as well as the database whose stored proc am calling are "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production"
The data am pulling from is my Project Team's remote database having Al32UTF8 charset and then am pushing this data as input parameter to Stored Proc to another Team's remote database. They precisely have a oracle tab type as parameter which has a date field in it .